# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I am trying using reflectData class for my avro schema. The code is:

```
File myFile = new File("MyFile.java");
ReflectData reflectData = ReflectData.get();
reflectData.getSchema(myFile)
```

When I try running this code in main, it gets executed as expected. Means there is no issue with dependencies.
But when I put the code in the method `actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e)` and run the plugin, I get the error Cannot initialize relfectData class like this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData`.
I am not very good at java/springboot so might be missing something. Would really appreciate any help here.
Here is my grade file

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.12.0"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Configure Gradle IntelliJ Plugin
// Read more: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html
intellij {
    version.set("2022.2.1")
    type.set("IC") // Target IDE Platform

    plugins.set(listOf(/* Plugin Dependencies */"java"))
}

dependencies {
    // Other dependencies
    implementation("org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.1")
}

tasks {
    // Set the JVM compatibility versions
    withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = "11"
        targetCompatibility = "11"
    }

    patchPluginXml {
        sinceBuild.set("213")
        untilBuild.set("223.*")
    }

}
```

Comment: It means that the library, probably `org.apache.avro`, isn't on the class path or included in the libraries that your version of Spring uses.  You'll need to do that.  If this is on your workstation, you'll need to download that library and then add it to either your project in IntelliJ or to your local Spring boot server, just depending on what's best for you.

Comment: But I have added this in ```build.gradle.kts``` file like this
```dependencies {
    // Other dependencies
    implementation("org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.1")
}
``` Wont it download the library?

Comment: But where does that install the library?  Does that set the class path for you?  We'd need more information about your environment to know what is really happening.

Comment: We need to see the **stacktrace** for the exception that was thrown while the JVM was initializing `ReflectData`.

Comment: @markspace - I don't think it means that.  Its not a missing class.  Its an uncaught exception during static initialization.  We need to see >that< stacktrace.

Comment: Dont know why but got this issue solved by downgrading the avro schema dependency to 1.9.2

Comment: But now unable to fetch the class from java file

Comment: @StephenC not getting any error in console, it keeps on running, identified the error in debug mode